# Copy a mongo db collection without locking whole mongod instance

Tags: mongodb, archive

I am trying to run mongodb copy collection on same server.
Requirement is we delete database as per our archival policy but we need to keep one collection from this data as a backup in separate db on same server.
I run copyCollection but it takes lock on whole mongo instance and block all other operations.
Collection size is 10 GB so it takes considerable time while copying and system is unavailable for duration.
Please suggest a way to achieve this without locking whole instance.

Comment: why using "db.collection.copyTo()" it's Deprecated since version 3.0.

Comment: Ya i checked that so i am looking for another solution now.

Comment: Yes you can do that through "mongoexport" and "mongoimport" shell command. If you are doing the  query on the same mongod server.

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to run mongodb copy collection on same server. Requirement
>   is we delete database as per our archival policy but we need to keep
>   one collection from this data as a backup in separate db on same
>   server.

Yes, it's possible through `mongoexport` from your `source` db and `mongoimport` the collection to the `target` database on the same `mongod` server.

Let's start from beginning.

Suppose that i have two database **`StackExchange`** and **`StackOverflow`** in same `mongod`.

```
> show dbs
StackExchange     0.000GB
StackOverflow     0.000GB
```

Suppose that in `StackExchange` there is collection **`orders`** having **`4`** documents.

```
> show collections
orders
>
```

Let's check there is `documents` records in `Orders` collection exist in `StackExchange` or not through `mongo` shell.

```
 > db.orders.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea526"),
        "cust_id" : "A123",
        "amount" : 250,
        "status" : "A"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea525"),
        "cust_id" : "A123",
        "amount" : 500,
        "status" : "A"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea528"),
        "cust_id" : "A123",
        "amount" : 300,
        "status" : "D"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea527"),
        "cust_id" : "B212",
        "amount" : 200,
        "status" : "A"
}
>
```

Here, as we can see that there is 4 document records in orders collection.

Suppose that  i want to copy the **`orders`** collection of  **`StackExchange`** `database` to the target database **`StackOverflow`** with **`targetorders`** `documents` name.

```
>mongoexport -d StackExchange -c orders | mongoimport -d StackOverflow -c targetorders
2018-02-14T10:52:16.630+0300    connected to: localhost
2018-02-14T10:52:16.631+0300    exported 4 records
2018-02-14T10:52:16.693+0300    connected to: localhost
2018-02-14T10:52:17.047+0300    imported 4 documents
```

To verify the `targetorders` collection documents in `StackOverflow` database.

```
> use StackOverflow
switched to db StackOverflow
> show collections
targetorders
test
> db.targetorders.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea528"),
        "cust_id" : "A123",
        "amount" : 300,
        "status" : "D"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea525"),
        "cust_id" : "A123",
        "amount" : 500,
        "status" : "A"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea526"),
        "cust_id" : "A123",
        "amount" : 250,
        "status" : "A"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea527"),
        "cust_id" : "B212",
        "amount" : 200,
        "status" : "A"
}
>
```

So, here we can see all the `4` documents of `orders` collection from the **`StackExchange`** has successfully copied in **`StackOverflow`**.

> **`Very Import Note:`** Run **`mongoexport`** & **`mongoimport`** from the **`system command line`**, **not** the mongo shell.

Hope this will help out to you.

For further your ref [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) and [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)